Ошибка Call to a member function get_title() on bool в woocommerce
Не могу понять почему код
$product = wc_get_product( 142 );
echo $product->get_title();

из woocommerce не может быть запущен в functions.php.
Выводит ошибку

Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_title() on bool in...

В чём может быть причина?

В том что wc_get_product( 142 ) возвращает false, но вообще каким образом Вы ее "запускаете" в functions.php?

Ну, вообще таким образом: function test_title() {
$product = wc_get_product( 142 );
echo $product->get_title();
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'test_title' );
У меня на сайте логика через js реализована, и нужны некоторые данные из woocommerce. Я хотел примерно таким способом информацию записать в переменные, а потом их использовать в js. Есть какой-то более правильный способ, если мне допустим имя товара нужно узнать по id?

Функция wc_get_product() может быть вызвана только по окончании init action, хук after_setup_theme будет выполнен до init. Если логика на JS, используйте Ajax или WordPress/WooCommerce REST API. В данном контексте не совсем пойму, чем вывод тайтла на данный хук Вам помогает

У меня довольно специфичная задача, этот код я в качестве примера использовал. Как я понял, что бы использовать REST API я получаю ключ в настройках woocommerce и с его помощью могу получить доступ. Я смог скачать через postman список товаров из магазина. А как это сделать на сайте? И где именно это нужно делать (php, js)?

И я так понял, что могу в некоторых задачах просто хук init установить и всё будет работать.
